# Short story about a girl with a spider in her hair

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find the name of a short story I read around 2002-2003 as an e-book from the now-defunct fictionwise.com. It could have been a free book from them, implying it was either a recent award nominee or an older story (I remember reading [Sandkings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandkings_(novelette)) around the same time).

A schoolgirl (grade school or high school) is regularly bullied by her classmates. She wakes up one morning from friendly, comforting dreams with small bites around her scalp. Somehow, either through her dreams or some other mental link, she comes to realize that there is an intelligent (alien?) spider nesting in her hair. The spider might be the last of her species and is about to die, and needs a human host, who will also die in the process, to hatch her brood.

The girl's bond with the spider grows and she decides to let the spider lay her eggs, sacrificing herself to help the spider who has been kind and understanding towards her. She puts her hair up and pretends to be sick for a few days to hide the spider from her parents and give its eggs time to develop. At the end, the brood of spiders bursts from the now-dead girl's body and one of the newborn spiders, remembering the name of the leader of the girl's bullies, scurries towards the school to target that bully.

Comment: sounds kinda like: http://www.scaryforkids.com/the-red-spot/

Comment: Unfortunately, Sandkings was first published 20 years earlier than when you read it. However, the association still might be useful if you can confirm that you read the two in the same anthology or magazine issue.